# The meaning of 'work'

Tags: word-meaning

I understand that work can mean the place where you do your job.

Which of the following 'work' has the above meaning?

1. I leave for work at 7.30 every morning.
2. I go to work by bus.
3. I get to/ arrive at work at nine.
4. I am usually at work till six.
5. Luckily, I don't get ill very much so I'm not often off work.

Can anyone also please explain what it means by 'off work' in the fifth item listed above?

Comment: _Off work_ = absent from my job. !-3 can be understood to mean 'my place of work'. _At work_ can mean either 'at my place of work' or 'working'.

Comment: More accurately, ***work** can mean the **place** where you do your **work***. Same as *I go to **Badminton** after work* (where '**Badminton**' means *the **place** where I do / play Badminton*, and 'work' means *the **activity** of working*, not the place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first four mean "the place where you do your job"

"Off work" is an idiom that means "absent". That is not at work, and not working. (and not working from home either). You might be "off work" because of illness or for a holiday.